# AWS trusted adviser vs Inspector

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am preparing for an AWS certificate so I am reading about AWS services. The security section states there are both AWS Trusted Advisor and AWS Inspector, however, I couldn't understand the difference between them.

What is the difference between AWS Trusted Advisor and AWS Inspector?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Trusted Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/) provides advice about your AWS Account in the areas of:

- Cost Optimization
- Fault Tolerance
- Performance
- Service Limits
- Security

[image: AWS Trusted Advisor]

It highlights potential problems with the way you use AWS.

---

[Amazon Inspector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_introduction.html) checks the configuration of EC2 instances. An agent runs on EC2 instances and checks operating system patches, known vulnerabilities, and common issues.

[image: Amazon Inspector]

---

Therefore, the difference is:

- Trusted Advisor applies to the AWS account and AWS services
- Amazon Inspector applies to the content of multiple EC2 instances

Comment: Correct. It only works *within* EC2 instances. Trusted Advisor works at the level of *AWS Services*.

Answer (score 2):

| AWS Inspector | AWS Trusted Advisor |
| --- | --- |
| Agent-based | Agent-less |
| No impact on performance | Improves performance by checking service limit |
| Free tier | Premium support |
| EC2 configuration | AWS account & administrations |
| No cost recommendations | Recommendations to optimize cost |
| Scheduled | Real time guidance |
| No impact on performance | Improves performance by checking service limit |

[image: AWS Inspector Vs AWS Trusted Advisor]